# What really is the essence of POJOs/models or domain-driven objects in the situation in context considering business requirements changes?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, model, pojo

I was told this chunk of code is a really nasty anti-pattern.

```
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private static Map<String, Object> getArgs(Object obj) {
    return new HashMap<>((Map<String, Object>) obj);
  }

  public void buildAndUpdateCustomer(List<Object> list) {
    for (Object obj : list) {
      Map<String, Object> args = getArgs(obj);
      daoProvider.updateCustomerName(args);
      daoProvider.updateAgingMia(args);
    }
  }

  public void buildAndUpdateTax(List<Object> list) {
    for (Object obj : list) {
      Map<String, Object> args = getArgs(obj);
      daoProvider.updateTaxAmount(args);
    }
  }

  public void buildAndUpdateLedgerBal(List<Object> list) {
    for (Object obj : list) {
      Map<String, Object> args = getArgs(obj);
      daoProvider.updateLedgerBalance(args);
    }
  }
```

An argument for that is because:

- It removes all of the type safety the compiler provides and even
  removes the name checking.
- Contains unnecessary casts `(Map<String,Object>) obj`
- Difficulty understanding what a method does by its signature because
  method parameters are of Object type. `List<Object> list`

---

My `List<Object> list` could be a list of invoice tax amounts, list of customers, list of ledger balances et cetera...which could be rewritten like this.

```
public void buildAndUpdateCustomer(List<Customer> list) {...}
public void buildAndUpdateTax(List<Tax> list) {..}
public void buildAndUpdateLedgerBal(List<Ledger> list) {..}
```

This means having to create Customer,Tax and Ledger POJO/entity/domain objects for each method. I have got over 100 `buildAndUpdate()` of these sort of methods updating and doing different things, do i have to create 100 of these POJO/entity/domain objects?? Maybe this is bad practice but i feel like having to add classes all over the place bloats the entire code base and kills maintainability.

Comment: "Adding classes all over the place" is kind of what OOP *is*. If you actually need collections of disparate types then use an interface-that's what they're for.

Comment: @DaveNewton please can you give a sample code of what this would look like?

Comment: You’d have an interface that includes `buildAndUpdate` then have a `List<BuildAndUpdate>` or whatever it’s called. Then you can call `buildAndUpdate` on whatever’s in it. Not sure what else you’d need as an example-it’s pretty standard Java OOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically ask why not use `Map<String, Object>` instead of domain objects.

I can't imagine too many things which are worse for maintainability than `Map<String, Object>`. Heara are just a few reasons:

- As a developer you'll have no idea which fields are allowed or are mandatory, and which types do they have - unless you dig through the source code.
- As for digging through the source code, since it's just `Map<String, Object>` it's hard to know where this pseudo-class is actually used. Unlike "find references" of a normal class.
- You domain objects may have additional utility methods, for instance providing easier access for data.
- You can't enforce rules in `Map<String, Object>`. Basically, you can create a instance which is invalid from the business logic point of view.
- Refactoring. Imagine you'd need to rename a field. Good luck finding all those places this field may be accessed.

So, yes, I'd definitely create a 100 domain objects.